# MacBook hangs on shutdown. It shows a progress spinner on black background. (Verbose printout included)

Tags: shutdown

I have a macbook air 1.4 Core i5 with macOS sierra.

It hangs every time I shut it down. Thus, I cannot update it to high sierra.

Using command+v I was able to screenshot the printout during the shutdown sequence.

```
Failed to send exception EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY. error code: 5 for pid 97
Process mds_stores [210] disabling system-wide I/O Throttling
Process mds_stores [210] disabling system-wide CPU Throttling
AppleActuatorDeviceUserClient::stop Entered
IO88211Inferface::updateReport _peerManager is missing
awdl0: promiscuous mode disable succeeded
```

Then no more progress. (see screenshot)

[image]

Edit:

After some Googling, I read that peerManager is connected to the wifi. Thus, I disabled the wifi before shutdown. The peerManager error went away but the system still hung. It displayed no printout. See image:

[image]

Hangs on this.

As additional information, the problem has been occurring for over 3 years and survived multiple major OS updates.

Comment: So this laptop has always hung at shutdown? For three years?

Comment: @IconDaemon correct. I have to hold down the power button to complete the shutdown. In the beginning it didn't do that (first few months), but at some point it started doing it.

Comment: Something else is drastically wrong as that is not the correct way to shutdown. Have you ever wiped the HD and done a [reinstallation of macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)? Make sure you have a Time Machine or other backup before you proceed!